# How do I generate a stroked font using python-fontforge

Tags: python, fonts, fontforge

I'm using python/fontforge to convert a CAD font to Truetype so that I can integrate it with SVG.

```
 import fontforge
 font=fontforge.font()
 font.strokedfont=1
 char=font.createChar(65)
 char.stroke("circular",5)
 pen=font[65].glyphPen()
 pen.moveTo(26,102)
 pen.lineTo(26,204)
 pen.lineTo(128,409)
 pen.lineTo(231,204)
 pen.lineTo(231,102)
 pen.endPath()
 pen.moveTo(26,204)
 pen.lineTo(231,204)
 pen.endPath()
 char.width=235
 font.generate('/tmp/testfont.ttf')
```

This gives me the letter "Capital A", but the font is filled in.

I'm expecting to see a vertical stroked line from (26,102) up to (26,204), rising to the apex at (128,409), falling to (231,204) and dropping vertically to (231,102). Then a horizontal stroke from (26,204) to (231,204).

Instead I have a blacked-out shape.

[image: blacked out shape]
[image: editor showing the lines defining the blacked out shape]

Obviously, `pen.endPath()` is not leaving the path open as expected and `charstroke("circular",5)` is not setting the path's thickness.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the `char.stroke("circular",20)` method **after drawing the path**. (after the second `pen.endPath()`)

**Tested on fontforge V20201107**

```
import fontforge
font=fontforge.font()
font.strokedfont=1
char=font.createChar(65)
pen=font[65].glyphPen()
pen.moveTo(26,102)
pen.lineTo(26,204)
pen.lineTo(128,409)
pen.lineTo(231,204)
pen.lineTo(231,102)
pen.endPath()
pen.moveTo(26,204)
pen.lineTo(231,204)
pen.endPath()
char.width=235
char.stroke("circular",20)
font.generate('/tmp/testfont.ttf')
```

Comment: You Beauty! I'm ecstatic!